# Distributed search using solrj?

Tags: solr, solrj

Can I perform a distributed search using solrj? If so how? (note : not solr)

I don't find any documentation in this aspect. Kindly help me if you find any/have used this before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your shards are:

"localhost:8983/solr" and "localhost:7574/solr"

You may perform a distributed search with solrj like:

```
String shards = "localhost:8983/solr,localhost:7574/solr";
StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer();
request.append("&q=" + query);
request.append("&shards=" + shards);
SolrParams solrParams = SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(request
                .toString());
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(solrParams);
```

alternatively, you may use the ModifiableSolrParams class:

```
String shards = "localhost:8983/solr,localhost:7574/solr";
ModifiableSolrParams solrParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
solrParams.set("q", query);
solrParams.set("shards", shards);
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(solrParams);
```

Comment: But using solr4j means you need to have a HttpSolrClient object which I presume, in this case, is server. How do you create it? (I have solr 5.3.0)